# Qt 4.8 how to do get properties of a QPushButton placed in a QList<QWidget *>?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpushbutton, qlist

Do someone know a solution to do get properties of a QPushButton placed in a QList<QWidget *> ?

```
.h
QList<QWidget *> list;

.cpp
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Push", this);
list->append(button);
qDebug() << list.at(0)->text(); // Not working : text() is not a property of QWidget but a property of QPushButton
```

Thx

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt. Either store QPushButton pointers or do a dynamic_cast<> or qobject_cast<> when you want to convert a QWidget to a QPushButton pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is more to do with `c++` and polymorphism in general rather than anything specific to `Qt`.  The expression...

```
list.at(0)
```

returns a `QWidget *`.  Hence the call...

```
list.at(0)->text()
```

fails to compile as `QWidget` has no member function named `text`.  If you think the pointer returned by `list.at(0)` points to a specific subclass of `QWidget` then you need to downcast it and check the result before using it.  e.g.

```
if (auto *b = dynamic_cast<QPushButton *>(list.at(0)))
    qDebug() << b->text();
```

Alternatively -- since you are using `Qt` -- you can make use of [`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast) in a similar fashion...

```
if (auto *b = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(list.at(0)))
    qDebug() << b->text();
```